# Using VBA to evaluate the formula and add the results to a range

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro to prepare some files and would like to include adding the below formula to each row as part of this automation. The formula is the same for each row but the trouble is the formula is very long.

```
=UPPER(CONCATENATE(IF(J2=0,"",AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(J2,"0",""))),IF(M2=0,"",LEN(M2)),IF(N2=0,"",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(N2,"0","")))),IF(P2=0,"",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(P2,"0","")))),IF(R2=0,"",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(R2,"0","")))),IF(W2=0,"",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(W2,"0","")))),IF(X2=0,"",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(X2,"0","")))),IF(Y2=0,"",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(Y2,"0","")))),IF(Z2=0,"",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Z2,"-","1"),".",""),"0","")),IF(AD2=0,"",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AD2,"-","1"),".",""),"0",""))))
```

I have tried recording the formula being added to help, but the result has parts of the macro deleted. Almost as if it is too long.

Could anybody provide a method to add this formula to each row? I have read you can evaluate a formula result in vba and return the results, rather than adding the formula to the sheet. Should I be looking at this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the module sheet put this declaration (under `Option Explicit` if it is there).

```
Public Const csFORMULA = "=UPPER(CONCATENATE(IF(J2=0,"""",AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(J2,""0"",""""))),IF(M2=0,"""",LEN(M2)),IF(N2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(N2,""0"","""")))),IF(P2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(P2,""0"","""")))),IF(R2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(R2,""0"","""")))),IF(W2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(W2,""0"","""")))),IF(X2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(X2,""0"","""")))),IF(Y2=0,"""",UPPER(AlphaNumericOnly(SUBSTITUTE(Y2,""0"","""")))),IF(Z2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Z2,""-"",""1""),""."",""""),""0"","""")),IF(AD2=0,"""",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AD2,""-"",""1""),""."",""""),""0"",""""))))"
```

Now you can fill the formula into any range. Example:

```
Range("L2:L10").Formula = csFORMULA
'Range("L2:L10") = Range("L2:L10").Value
```

The second commented line is in case you want to revert to values from teh inserted formula. Note that I'm using `.Formula` and not `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: There's probably no reason to declare the constant public, but kudos regardless.

Comment: @ckuhn203 - Yeah, it's probably overkill in this case. The *public* is because I tend to put all such formulas at the top of one module in larger projects and cannot call them from other module sheets without it. Now it's a habit for both large and small projects.